# In BTRFS, how to revert to previous version of file, if it's size is greater that remaining disk space?

Tags: btrfs

lets image this situation. I have 20GB file on btrfs disk that only has 10GB space left. I create snapshot and then I modify the file. How to revert that file to original that is stored in snapshot?
I think it is not possible. Yes I can mount the snapshot and then cp the file from snapshot back to main filesystem. But it will not fit, because it is larger than remaining space. So I could delete changed file to release the space? No, because deleting the file will not increase free space, it is btrfs.. In order to release the space, I would have to delete the snapshot, but in that way I will loose the original file.
So I think the only way is:

- mount the snapshot
- cp the file to external filesystem (external storage)
- delete changed file
- delete the snapshot
- copy original file from external storage back

Any thoughts about different solution?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible and quite easy. It may be enough just to `cp` with `--reflink=always`:

```
cp --reflink=always /path/to/desired/file /target/directory/
```

`--reflink=always` is crucial. Additionally you may want to use `-a`.

When in doubt, a reasonable approach is to copy to another name, i.e. not to overwrite the modified file rashly. This way you will be able to get success from `cp`, examine the result and make sure it's the right file in the right directory, before you overwrite the modified file (with `mv` in the target directory).

With recent enough Linux kernel ([5.18](https://btrfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Feature-by-version.html#id2) or above) the command should work, if only the desired file and the target directory are in the same Btrfs filesystem (and this is obviously your case).

If your kernel is not recent enough then you may get `Invalid cross-device link` error. You will get this error if you try to `cp --reflink=always` across mountpoints. It's still possible to reflink the desired file to the desired directory, you just need to do this under a single mountpoint. So if you get `Invalid cross-device link` then proceed like this:

1. Mount the whole Btrfs filesystem (`subvol=/`) in `/some/mountpoint`.

   The point is we want the desired file and the target directory to appear somewhere under `/some/mountpoint`. Depending on the layout (tree) of subvolumes in the filesystem, you may be able to do this by mounting some subvolume, not necessarily the whole filesystem. By mounting the whole filesystem you will achieve the desired result for sure.

   Maybe a mountpoint fulfilling this requirement already exists in your running OS and you can use it. Compare this answer: [btrfs: browsing subvolumes](https://superuser.com/a/1396270/432690).
2. Use `cp --reflink=always` to copy the desired file to the target directory, just like above. The important thing is to stay under `/some/mountpoint`, even if the subvolume with the target directory is (also) mounted elsewhere. Do not cross mountpoints. Mounting the whole filesystem at one mountpoint was exactly to allow you to `cp` under a single mountpoint.
3. `umount /some/mountpoint` (unless you used an already existing mount).

Comment: Note that, since Linux 5.18, you are able to reflink copy across mount points if it's the same fs.

Comment: @Atemu That's great; I'm unable to test this at the moment though. Can you share some (semi-)official link documenting the feature? I want to improve my answer, but I don't want to base solely on your word. (Don't get me wrong, personally I do believe you, but writing good answers is more demanding.) 5.18 is not (yet) listed [here](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Changelog). I have found [this](https://lore.kernel.org/linux-btrfs/cover.1645194730.git.josef@toxicpanda.com/T/#mf251325026fe2e15ed5119856bf654ba4f0d298b) but I'm not sure how to get to the kernel version that implements it.

Comment: https://btrfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Feature-by-version.html#id2, https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=9f5710bbfd3031dd7ce244fa26fba896d35f5342, https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=ae460f058e9ff31946cc393bf897fc44483f0876

Comment: @Atemu Thank you for the links.